# Where does Exchange Server store its certificates?

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm trying to track down the Exchange cert with DN:

`N=<XXX>,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft`

No luck yet finding it via MMC.  Does anyone know where this certificate lives?

Answer (score 1):

Open up MMC console and add the 'Certificate' snap-in, select computer account rather then user account.

The cert is usually located in the Personal > Certificates folder.

But pleaseeee do not make changes via this, always use the Exchange Management Shell, you will cause more headache then you want otherwise.

If you can't find the cert, then it hasn't been installed properly. Open up EMS and enter Get-ExchangeCertificate | fl, check the certificate is there.

Comment: from EMS I get several certs back, but not one for "Administrative Groups"

Comment: Why would it be for "Administrative Groups"?

Comment: @Shane Madden I'm trying to find the cert corresponding to the DN in the question

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't believe the certificate's subject field will match the server object's LDAP distinguished name.. can you clarify what led you down this path and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Shane Madden sure -- all I know is the DN (it comes from a third party source) and I want more information on it (e.g. where did it come from?  what other metadata is available?).  I had assumed it originated from an x509 certificate, but now I'm not so sure.